# Cropping frames from videos with positions

Tags: python, tensorflow, vector, parallel-processing, pytorch

I am reading videos using [torchvision](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.io.read_video.html). Have JSON files that show face positions in each frame. JSON has the frame number as key and position of face(s) in that frame like this:

```
{'0': [[307.6858215332031,
   111.24893188476562,
   418.0126037597656,
   263.04254150390625]]}
```

I am able to extract faces from individual frames using this code:

```
def crop_frame(frame, face_position):
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = [int(b * 2) for b in face_position]
    w = xmax - xmin
    h = ymax - ymin
    p_h = 0
    p_w = 0

    if h > w:
        p_w = int((h-w)/2)
    elif h < w:
        p_h = int((w-h)/2)
    crop = frame[max(ymin - p_h, 0):ymax + p_h, max(xmin - p_w, 0):xmax + p_w]
    return crop
```

For extracting faces from the dataset (which is really big with more than 100K videos), I am not able to justify using for loop as it will be take much time.
Things I tried:

- Using map function. But PyTorch, numpy, etc don't have a [map function](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/fast-way-to-use-map-in-pytorch/70814/2).
- Creating a PyTorch Dataset and  use [data loader](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader) to parallelize face extraction at video level like using multiple num_workers.

```
class VideoCropsDataset:
    """
    Take a video and extract crops using json file
    """
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.df)
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        video, audio, fps = torchvision.io.read_video(video_path)
        with open(json_path, "r") as bbox_f:
            face_dict = json.load(bbox_f)
        crops = []
        for i in range(len(video)):
            crop = extract_crop(video[i], face_dict[str(i)])
            crops.append(crop)
        return crop
```

In this way, I'll be able to use parallelism for multiple videos.

- Use TensorFlow [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn). But I need audio and video together and want to save data as numpy arrays to be used later on.

Is there a better way I can solve this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: maybe you should use fast severs on network - i.e. `Google Colabs`

Comment: I already have faster virtual machines.

Comment: How about just  return images and crop positions in dataset's getitem, and rewrite the crop function to work on a batch of frames.  Working on a batch should theoretically make it faster. This way you can also utilize cuda for cropping.